# Du Val Singularities and ADE singularities

Tags: algebraic-geometry, singularity

I know this might be a stupid question but while I am reading several lecture notes.I am wondering are Du Val Singularities and ADE singularities the same thing? And what is the best book to read if I want to know more about singularity theory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several names that are being used:

Du Val singularities, singularities of type ADE, rational double points, simple surface singularities, ...

and they all refer to the isolated surface singularities that are classified by the Dynkin diagrams of type $A_n$, $D_n$, $E_6$, $E_7$ and $E_8$ as far as I know.

There are some nice introductory [notes](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masda/surf/more/DuVal.pdf) by Miles Reid and some other good [notes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0506107.pdf) by Benjamin Friedrich, but also [this article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2373050?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) by Michael Artin is one of the standard ressources as far as I know. The article [15 Characterizations of rational double points](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/487c/952ef52e4c13b852b387d7df84c1fbfbdadc.pdf?_ga=2.200778990.1164672218.1568062860-352922100.1568062860) by Alan Durfee also always sounded promising to me, but I have never looked into it myself.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will have a look of those!